# comparing values from a multi-value parameter to a dataset column in SSRS

Tags: stored-procedures, reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2012

I have a dataset created from a stored procedure by passing it a multi-value parameter. What I now need is to check whether all values from the parameter came back in a specific column of my result set or not, and if not, then display those values in the report.

So, for example, if I'm passing values 'a', 'b', 'c' and 'd' to my parameter, and if my dataset column only contains 'a' and 'd', then I need a way to display 'b' and 'c' on the report.

Thanks,
Pratik

Comment: What data type is you column? It could be done with custom code.

Comment: Its a varchar. Even I thought of custom code, the place where I'm getting stuck is traversing through all the unique values of my column, I'm not ale to figure that part out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll need a query that is supplying the values for your parameter. The query might look something like this:

```
select 'a' as ParamValue
union all
select 'b' as ParamValue
union all
select 'c' as ParamValue
union all
select 'd' as ParamValue
```

Set you parameter values to be populated by this query:
[image]

Now Add a table that can list your parameter values.

[image]

Next, you can check if each value exists in your main dataset using a [Lookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx) function like this:

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Lookup(Fields!PARAMVALUE.Value,Fields!COLVALUE.Value,Fields!COLVALUE.Value, "MainDataSet")), True, False)
```

You can use this as a filter to just show the parameter values where this function doesn't return a value:

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't get you there when you say that I'll need a query for supplying values for my paramter, the parameter will be getting values from end users at run-time

Comment: I don't have a predefined list of values which can be supplied to the parameter, I mean it can be all that is there in my dataset column plus some more. So in a scenario like this, I'm not sure how can I construct a query for a dataset that gets values from my parameter.

Comment: Is the parameter a textbox where users can type in any values they want?

Comment: Got it working! Combined your solution with the one given here [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6880ed62-5cab-4e78-8742-103f377c8402/forum-faq-how-to-show-top-n-selected-parameter-values-from-a-specified-parameter-on-the-report?forum=sqlreportingservices)

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the stored procedure (or make a new one based on the old one for this report)? If so, then you could change from an `INNER JOIN` to an `OUTER JOIN` and get that result. For example, if your stored procedure showed how much clients were billed last month and looked like:

```
SELECT ClientName, SUM(BillAmount) AS TotalBilled
FROM Clients
INNER JOIN Bills ON Clients.ClientId = Bills.ClientId AND Bills.BillDate >= DateAdd(m, -1, GetDate())
WHERE ClientId IN @ClientIds
GROUP BY ClientName
ORDER BY ClientName
```

then this would exclude any clients not billed. If you change to an `OUTER JOIN` like so:

```
SELECT ClientName, SUM(BillAmount) AS TotalBilled
FROM Clients
LEFT OUTER JOIN Bills ON Clients.ClientId = Bills.ClientId AND Bills.BillDate >= DateAdd(m, -1, GetDate())
WHERE ClientId IN @ClientIds
GROUP BY ClientName
ORDER BY ClientName
```

then clients with no bills would still show with a `Null` amount for the amount billed

Comment: I'm afrad changing the stored procedure is not going to be possible/